# does sequence of columns in where condition matters the sequence of composite key? in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, performance, performance-tuning, query-performance

here, In the code where `exists clause` contains all primary key columns in `where`, I want to know that the sequence of this columns in it, matters in query performance.

```
  update temp_fd_dtl_svj a
  set a.LAST_INT_PAID_DT = ( select max(b.TRAN_DT) from temp_fd_int_svj b
                              where a.COMP_CD = b.comp_cd and a.BRANCH_CD = b.BRANCH_CD and a.ACCT_CD = b.ACCT_CD
                                and a.ACCT_TYPE = b.ACCT_TYPE and a.fd_no = b.FD_NO and b.Tran_type in ('I')
                            )
  , a.LAST_PROV_DT = ( select max(b.TRAN_DT) from temp_fd_int_svj b
                              where a.COMP_CD = b.comp_cd and a.BRANCH_CD = b.BRANCH_CD and a.ACCT_CD = b.ACCT_CD
                                and a.ACCT_TYPE = b.ACCT_TYPE and a.fd_no = b.FD_NO and b.Tran_type in ('P')
                            )
   , a.LAST_TDS_DT = ( select max(b.TRAN_DT) from temp_fd_int_svj b
                              where a.COMP_CD = b.comp_cd and a.BRANCH_CD = b.BRANCH_CD and a.ACCT_CD = b.ACCT_CD
                                and a.ACCT_TYPE = b.ACCT_TYPE and a.fd_no = b.FD_NO and b.Tran_type in ('T')
                            )
  where exists (select *
                from temp_fd_int_svj c
               where a.acct_cd = c.acct_CD
                 and a.comp_cd = c.comp_cd
                 and a.BRANCH_CD = c.BRANCH_CD
                 AND a.ACCT_TYPE = c.ACCT_TYPE
                 and a.fd_no = c.FD_NO
               )
  ;
```

Comment: 1) The order of conditions in WHERE clause matters nothing. The optimizer will still re-sort them as it wants. 2) Do not use `SELECT *` in `WHERE EXISTS` - you need not record, but the record existence fact only, so some `SELECT 1` is more safe.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not matter. Make sure:

1. Data types are same in both tables
2. All columns are indexed  Index
3. Index statistics are not stale.

   SELECT stale_stats FROM user_ind_statistics
   WHERE index_name = upper('&index_name');

Answer (score 0):

/* Formatted on 20/3/2019 03:00:33 p. m. (QP5 v5.326) */
UPDATE temp_fd_dtl_svj a
SET a.last_int_paid_dt   = (SELECT MAX (b.tran_dt)
                            FROM temp_fd_int_svj b
                            WHERE     a.comp_cd = b.comp_cd
                                  AND a.branch_cd = b.branch_cd
                                  AND a.acct_cd = b.acct_cd
                                  AND a.acct_type = b.acct_type
                                  AND a.fd_no = b.fd_no
                                  AND b.tran_type IN ('I')),
    a.last_prov_dt       = (SELECT MAX (b.tran_dt)
                            FROM temp_fd_int_svj b
                            WHERE     a.comp_cd = b.comp_cd
                                  AND a.branch_cd = b.branch_cd
                                  AND a.acct_cd = b.acct_cd
                                  AND a.acct_type = b.acct_type
                                  AND a.fd_no = b.fd_no
                                  AND b.tran_type IN ('P')),
    a.last_tds_dt        = (SELECT MAX (b.tran_dt)
                            FROM temp_fd_int_svj b
                            WHERE     a.comp_cd = b.comp_cd
                                  AND a.branch_cd = b.branch_cd
                                  AND a.acct_cd = b.acct_cd
                                  AND a.acct_type = b.acct_type
                                  AND a.fd_no = b.fd_no
                                  AND b.tran_type IN ('T'))
WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1 /*DO NOT SELECT ALL COLUMNS, 1 IS RIGHT*/
           FROM temp_fd_int_svj c
           WHERE     a.acct_cd = c.acct_cd
                 AND a.comp_cd = c.comp_cd
                 AND a.branch_cd = c.branch_cd
                 AND a.acct_type = c.acct_type
                 AND a.fd_no = c.fd_no);